# Debian on Hyper-V

Tags: debian, hyper-v, linux-kernel, legacy

I installed Debian with kernel 2.6.32-5-686 on a Hyper-V virtual machine. I had to add a legacy network card.
I follow this tutorial http://www.yusufozturk.info/linux-server/debian-2-6-36-kernel-upgrade-for-hyper-v-client-drivers.html to add Hyper-V driver but when I reboot with the new kernel i got this error:

> BLKVSC_DRV: blkvsc_probe() ERROR!! register_blkdev() failed! ret -16

And at the very first boot log (that i can not copy because i did not find it in dmesg or boot log) i see a mount /dev error.

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Debian are you running? That blog talks about a newer kernel than you mention; is there a particular reason? What do you mean by "crash"? Error messages?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze). I tried to recompile the kernel v. 2.6.36 as the blog said, but i did not unserstand why that version. During bootup I saw a list of number as matrix ex.[15 12 35 94 86] and after a few it freeze...

Comment: I edited the topic because using a compile deb package i solve that boot freeze, however i still have some error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stay away from any in-kernel Hyper-V drivers based on anything let's around say 3.0, since early version were considered staging and were sometimes utterly unstable.

Hyper-V drivers got fully integrated upstream (moved out of staging) with 3.4. While Debian Wheezy (7.0) will be based on 3.2, it will contain a backport from Kernel 3.4, I'm using it here.

Thus said for squeeze: Install with legacy NIC and IDE only drives, then get the Wheezy kernel from squeeze-backports and reboot. Then you'll be able to use paravirt NIC, SCSI disks, additionally you'll get mouse integration and support for more than 1 vCPU.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you be a little more verbose about "then get the Wheezy kernel from squeeze-backports and reboot"?

Comment: In corner cases like this I usually just fetch the latest kernel from kernel.org and recompile it in the Debian Way™. For example, one of the backup servers I need to keep my eye on was very unreliable with Debian Squeeze default kernel; iSCSI support is a bit flaky on that one. I compiled my own kernel 3.x, now the server uptime is about one year, no problems whatsoever.

Comment: @Tobia that might be good fodder for a separate follow-up question

Answer (score 3):

Debian Wheezy (7.0) contains a backport Hyper-V drivers from Kernel 3.4

But the Hyper-V kernel modules, at minimum:

- hv_vmbus
- hv_utils
- hv_storvsc
- hv_netvsc

are missing in the installer image of Debian Wheezy created before 2012-11-13

Solution:

You need use .iso created after 2012-11-14, or the `.iso` by Arnaud Patard

[See details here](http://vvm.blog.tut.by/2012/11/02/debian-on-hyper-v/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://docs.homelinux.org/doku.php?id=using_linux_ic_with_debian_squeeze the kernels there have the storvsc ata_piix fix ;)

Comment: Seems good, but is there also i386 version?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to install Debian 7 (wheezy) on hyper-V.
Currently, the netinst image doesn't contains the hyper-v drivers. (tested with netinst beta 2). You may replace your network card by a legacy network card, but it won't be enough since the debian Netinst does not detect the disk, so you can't install anything.

The solution I use is to download the Debian 6 netinst "business card". Add a "legacy network card", and boot on the install disc.

When netinst ask you for the hostname for your new system, switch to another console (Alt-F2) and type

```
echo wheezy > /etc/default-release
```

Then return to the first console (Alt-F1) and proceed.
At the end of the installation, you will have a working Debian 7 (Wheezy), with modern kernel that support Hyper-V. So you may remove the legacy network card and use the native driver for network and disk.

Comment: By now this issue with thet netboot ISO has been resolved, you can now yank in the latest daily builds (and thus likely the final builds once it's you) and have working storage without additionaly hacking.

Answer (score 1):

With Debian jessie the hyper-v stuff is no more a problem, the modules are already integrated and are stable. You need only to compile and install the hyper-v tools (kvp and vss), I found this howto: http://docs.homelinux.org/hyper-v:debian_jessie_hyper-v and all will be fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Debian 6.0 (Squeeze), You can upgrade to 7.0 (Wheezy), it’s so simple:
just answer Y every time.

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and replace every `squeeze` with `wheezy`, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, Y,enter.

```
apt-get update  
apt-get upgrade  
apt-get dist-upgrade  
reboot
```

your new kernel will be selected, login, then you can `lsmod | grep hv` and see the hyper-v modules loaded (hv_vmbus, hv_netvsc, hv_blkvsc, hv_storvsc), connect your non-legacy network adapter and do `ip show link` then you’ll see it (you can be sure by checking the MAC).
But why stay there?, now you can go to Debian 8.2 (jessie) by following the same instructions but this time use “jessie” on your sourcelist.
I wasn’t able to go directly from 6 to 8.
If you have trouble with “public key is not available” then follow instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139127/how-to-trust-a-apt-repository-debian-apt-get-update-error-public-key-is-not-av).

Sometimes running on Hyper-v it throws two errors:

```
Error: Driver ‘pcspkr’ is already registered  
SMBus base address uninitialized – upgrade bios or use force_addr=0xaddr
```

to get rid of those errors just blacklist two modules by:

```
echo 'blacklist pcspkr' >> /etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf  
echo 'blacklist i2c_piix4' >> /etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf
```

then do:

```
update-initramfs -u  
reboot
```

Enjoy.